# Doctrine 2 incorrectly eager loading a many-to-one association?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, lazy-loading

I have a weird issue that I don't *think* is normal behaviour (at least I can't find any mention of it, and it seems incorrect). This is my association mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
*/
class Node extends Entity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Content", inversedBy="nodes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $content;

    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_class", type="string")
*/
abstract class Content extends Entity
{  
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Node", mappedBy="content")
     */
    protected $nodes;

    // ...
}
```

When I fetch a Node entity using:

```
$em->getRepository('Node')->find(1);
```

Doctrine **also** eager loads the associated Content entity, for no apparent reason? I know one-to-many associations are always eager loaded, but I didn't think many-to-one ones were?

I have checked exactly what's happening using the SQL logger and I see two separate queries to the database. I have no OnLoad listeners or anything like that. Explicitly setting `fetch="LAZY"` (what should be the default) doesn't have any effect.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, this is why:

> There is a general performance consideration with Class Table Inheritance: If you use a CTI entity as a many-to-one or one-to-one entity you should never use one of the classes at the upper levels of the inheritance hierachy as “targetEntity”, only those that have no subclasses. Otherwise Doctrine CANNOT create proxy instances of this entity and will ALWAYS load the entity eagerly.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html